# MySQL: Select non matching rows in a join

Tags: mysql, join

Table 1 contains a unique ID column with millions of rows.

Table 2 contains 2 columns, matchId1, matchId2 which can hold an ID from Table 1. There can be many rows in Table 2 referencing a given ID.

How can I list the IDs from Table 1 that are not contained in Table 2 (in either column) in an efficient way?

Comment: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: @valex: It's nice but how to apply it to two columns? I need to remove all rows that have either matchid1 or matchid2 set. A join on matchid1 will ignore matchid2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 on table1.id in (table2.matchId1,table2.matchId2)
WHERE table2.matchId1 IS NULL AND table2.matchId2 IS NULL
```

Comment: From the looks of it, it does exactly what I mean and is easy to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM table1 x
  LEFT
  JOIN table2 y
    ON y.id = x.id
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

or, more specifically...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM table1 x
  LEFT
  JOIN table2 y
    ON x.id IN(y.id1,y.id2)
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

This assumes that there is a single column PK on table2

Comment: I as looking for something similar yesterday and didn't find much. Stumbled upon this today, awesome. Cheers from me anyway.

Comment: OK, but this is just about the easiest question in RDBMS-land, so don't go overboard! ;-)

Comment: Soneone's having a laugh.

Comment: This is not what I need, I need y.id1 and y.id2 to matter in this. I already found such answers on SO. If y.id1 is null but y.id2 is not then I do not want this row. So it seems to me there has to be 2 joins (maybe through an union), I have no idea how to do this in a single request, and I have no idea how to do it efficiently at all

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions

Using jons

```
SELECT x.*
FROM table1 x
LEFT JOIN table2 y ON y.matchId1 = x.id
LEFT JOIN table2 z ON z.matchId2 = x.id
WHERE y.matchId1 IS NULL AND z.matchId2 IS NULL
```

Using IN

```
SELECT x.*
FROM table1 x
WHERE x.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT matchId1 FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT matchId2 FROM table2
)
```

Comment: Which do you think is the fastest? I had doubts that the first would work for my case since I didn't know if common rows from the joins would be interpreted as one row. BTW, you got a typo "jons" instead of "joins").

Comment: I would suspect the first query is more efficient, as I suspect MySQL will struggle to use any indexes on matchid1 / matchid2 in the 2nd query.